# How many males were participating in Olympiad?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Number of male participants in chess Olympiad is bigger $9$ times than number of female participants. Also number of accumulated points of males is $4$ times bigger than points of females. How many males were participating in Olympiad ?

(Olympiad was happening in two stages. Every chess player played two matches against other players one in white other in black. Winner got $1$ point draw $0.5$ point and loss $0$ point ).

Answer has $4$ options $a)9,b)7,c)3,d)21$. Obviously only looking answer we can say answer is a). But I tried to solve this question without that,  it seems easy but Icouldn't solve it. Can you help?

Comment: Please explain, in an edit to your post, why you think (a) is the "obvious answer"?

Comment: Let $F$ be the number of females, so $9F$ is the number of males.  Then there are already $9F\times (9F-1)=81F^2-9F$ clear male points (from the $MM$ games).  That's a lot.  there are only $F^2-F$ clear female points.  Now if females win *all* of the $MF$ games, that would give us an additional $2\times 9F\times F=18F^2$ female points.  I'd start from there.

Comment: Note:  as it stands, $a$ is the only possible answer since it is the only multiple of $9$.  Seems unlikely to have been intended.  Though it does work (under the assumption that females win all their matches).

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  it isn't true that the points scale the way you want.  The solution is indeed unique (ignoring the trivial solution in which nobody participates and there are no points).

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  But, again, it is.  Well, there are two if you count the degenerate one (with no players) but I assume we are meant to discount that one.  the issue is that the number of $MM$ games just grows too fast.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  You are wrong about the scaling.  There are at least $81F^2-9F$ male points and there are at most $F^2-F+18F^2=19F^2-F$ female points.  The former grows much faster than the latter.

Comment: @lulu What if females don't win all their matches?

Comment: @VardanDanielyan  That makes it worse, not better.

Comment: @lulu sorry it was silly question )

Comment: @VardanDanielyan  Oh, no.  It wasn't.  A priori it might have mattered, but it in the end it doesn't.  I'm writing something to post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the discussion in the comments:

The problem is bizarre in that only one option is a multiple of $9$, so one can declare $a)$ correct without even thinking about it.  But let's ignore that.

Let $F$ be the number of females, so that $9F$ is the number of males.

then:

there are $9F\times (9F-1)=81F^2-9F$ games of the form $MM$ so there are at least that many male points (each such game generates exactly one male point).

there are $F(F-1)=F^2-F$ games of the form $FF$.

and there are $2\times F\times 9F=18F^2$ games of the form $MF$

It follows that there at most $F^2-F+18F^2=19F^2-F$ female points (fewer if females lose or draw any of the $MF$ games).

Now the equation $$81F^2-9F=4\times (19F^2-F)$$ has exactly two solutions,

namely $F\in \{0,1\}$.

The case $F=0$ is degenerate (it's the case in which nobody participates and no points are awarded).  I assume we are meant to discard that one.

The other case $F=1$ corresponds to the given solution, $a)$.

To see there are no other solutions (even if we weaken the assumption that females win all the $MF$ games) note that $$F>1\implies 81F^2-9F>4\times (19F^2-F)$$ so weakening the assumption makes things worse, not better.  And we are done.